# Best way of template specializations for different types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

As looking into libraries, stackoverflow questions and articles on the web, it turns out there are two main way in C++11 to create template specializations (partial if needed) of the same functionality for different types:

### function template with SFINAE return type

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{    
    template <class T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type
    compute_thing(T n)
    {
        // do calculations and return something
    }

    template <class T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type
    compute_thing(T n)
    {
        // do calculations and return something
    }
}

template <class T>
T compute_thing(T n)
{
    return detail::compute_thing<T>(n);
}
```

### struct/class template with SFINAE partial specialization

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{    
    template <class T, class Enable = void>
    struct compute_thing;

    template <class T>
    struct compute_thing<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type>
    {
        static T call(T x)
        {
            // do calculations and return something
        }
    };

    template <class T>
    struct compute_thing<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type>
    {
        static T call(T x)
        {
            // do calculations and return something
        }
    };
}

template <class T>
T compute_thing(T n)
{
    return detail::compute_thing<T>::call(n);
}
```

However it's not clear:

- **Which style should be preferred and why?**
- What are the advantages/disadvantages in terms of reusability, versatility, compile-time and runtime performance?

Comment: The first style uses overloads, whereas the second uses (partial-)specialization.

Comment: A third way is tag dispatching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result would need some processing or would return a non-const value I would go with this solution, using functions:

```
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type compute_thing(T n)
{
    return some_integral_calc(n);
}

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type compute_thing(T n)
{
    return some_fp_calc(n);
}
```

But if I could make the compiler do the work of getting my const value (e.g. by a constexpr.) I would go with specialized structs when possible.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming#Compile-time_class_generation